# There is a method to convert these column in data format like this dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, notepad++, excel-2010

I need to convert these 3 column in one column with this format(gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss) [image]

I have tried with notepad++ but i fail
for example the final result will be 28/12/2022 16:54:00 or 2022.12.28 16:54:00

Comment: what kind of file is that??? csv?

Comment: could you specify what you have tried? Preferably with a bit of code. I am not familiar with gg/mm/aaaa format  is it the same as dd/mm/yyyy ? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ since the tags include excel I would assume they are using excel

Comment: the file format is .xls  - format is it the same as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: what fails? what result do you get? you only specify what you want to happen not what is working, you must provide useful information about what you have tried and what that attempt resulted in. There is no way for us to conclude what the issue might be or how to fix that issue.

Comment: I have tried to use formula to CONCATENATE these column but it fails

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `MID` formulas to extract years, days and months and `DATE` formula to make it a date. Use `TIME` formula to make time:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),RIGHT(A1,2))+TIME(B1,C1,0)
```

Don't forget to format it as custom (right click on cell -> Format cell -> Number -> Custom and write *dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss*

Or you can use `CONCATENATE` if value as time is not necessary:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1,":",C1,":00")
```

Results:
[image]